# windows 10 made to act like Windows 8 wants undoing

Tags: windows

A friend has a laptop which has been upgraded to Windows 10 but made to look like Windows 8. How can get it back to original Windows 10 version?

Comment: Welcome to superuser:If you could provide more detail, maybe a snip of the area that you wish to change we could help a little easyer. Until then maybe try... Turn on or off Tablet mode, change settings in start menu - from full screen to not full screen, recovery options - refresh win 10. The answer depends on which part of win 8 you are using. Please take a couple of minutes and read:- http://superuser.com/help .Answering: http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer, again welcome to superuser.Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have it set to tablet mode - there's a page in settings called, appropriately, tablet mode

These are the defaults

[image]

But you can set it to be always in desktop mode, and/or to ask before switching.